# htaccess rule to redirect from CodeIgniter to Wordpress category

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have to .htaccess files, one for CodeIgniter and one for Wordpress. My directory structure is as follows:

```
/application <-- CI Install
/news <-- WP Install
```

**Generally, I want to have a url `/resources` that rewrites to `/news/topics/resources`. Additionally, `/resources/page/2` should be rewritten to `/news/topics/resources/page/2`, etc...**

I've tried a couple of things to no avail. Listed below is my CodeIgniter and WP htaccess files:

CI .htaccess file (located at /.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

#This should redirect /news/topic/resources/ to /resources
#RewriteRule resources/ /news/topic/resources [NC]
#RewriteRule /resources/^(.*)\ /news/topic/resources/$1
#RewriteRule ^resources/ news/topic/resources/ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^resources$ news/index.php?cat=825 [L]
#RewriteRule ^resources/(.*)$ news/$1 [R,L]

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

WP .htaccess file (located at /news/.htaccess)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^resources.*$ /news/topic/$0 [NC]
```

Should do that. WP will generate 404 pages for URLs that don't exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I imagine it has something to do with the way Wordpress handles rewrites. Looking into wp_rewrite now.